# Mapping data: error in classIntervals: var is not numeric

Tags: r, maps, sp, maptools

When executing the 'classIntervals' command I got the error while mapping data from Eurostat.

```
library(rgdal)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(sp)
library(GISTools)
library(classInt)
library(maptools)
library(SmarterPoland)
library(reshape)
library(reshape2)

# create a new empty object called 'temp' in which to store a zip file
# containing boundary data
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
# now download the zip file from its location on the Eurostat website and
# put it into the temp object
  download.file("http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/cache/GISCO/geodatafiles/NUTS_2010_60M_SH.zip", temp)
# now unzip the boundary data
unzip(temp))
plot(EU_NUTS)

proj4string(EU_NUTS)

EU_NUTS <- spTransform(EU_NUTS, CRS("+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137  +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs"))

plot(EU_NUTS)

EurostatTOC <- getEurostatTOC()

head(EurostatTOC)

data <- getEurostatRCV(kod = "lfst_r_lfu3rt")

unique(data$age)
unique(data$sex)
unique(data$time)

sub_data <- subset(data, (age == "Y20-64") & (sex == "T") & (time == "2012 "))

mapdata <- cast(data, geo ~ time + age + sex)

head(mapdata)

head(EU_NUTS@data)

EU_NUTS@data = data.frame(EU_NUTS@data, mapdata[match(EU_NUTS@data[, "NUTS_ID"],
                                              mapdata[, "geo"]), ])

my_colours <- brewer.pal(5, "BuGn")

breaks <- classIntervals(EU_NUTS@data$X2012._Y20.64_T, n = 5, style =   "fisher", unique = TRUE)$brks

## Error in classIntervals(EU_NUTS@data$X2012._Y20.64_T, n = 5, style = "fisher",  :  var is not numeric
```

Comment: What does str() or class() tell you about the column? Perhapse it, in fact, is not numeric.

Comment: After the `unzip` line (which has an extra `)`), which file are you reading into EU_NUTS? There's five shapefiles in that zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done this:

```
breaks <- classIntervals(EU_NUTS@data$X2012._Y20.64_T,
      n = 5, style =   "fisher", unique = TRUE)$brks
```

which is trying to get a column called `"X2012._Y20.64_T"`. Does that exist?

```
> "X2012._Y20.64_T" %in% names(EU_NUTS)
[1] FALSE
```

No. There's something similar:

```
> "X2012_Y20.64_T" %in% names(EU_NUTS)
[1] TRUE
```

You've put an extra `.` in your column name. Remove that and it should work.